# How to get directory details programatically in Azure AD?

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory

I have registered a new Azure AD app for login functionality in existing vuejs and nodejs projects.

And I successfully set up login and logout functionality using `@azure/msal-node` npm package.

Now, I want to get the directory details after the user login to store that directory details in my local DB.

I have read many documents but didn't find any working solution. So, Please help me and share good documentation links that could be helpful for me.

After login, success get this response from Azure AD: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRBs0.png

Note:- I am referring this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal

Comment: Thanks for the answer @KartikBhiwapurkar,
I have one more question how to get logged in user Azure AD added domain and add a new domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   By following the given documentation link for creating a nodejs webapp using @azure-msal, you can get the **details of the signed in user through the token claims details shown in the output/results page wherein you can view it through the ‘View ID token’ link**. Thus, when the details are shown, you also have an option to **export these details to a database configured of your choice. But for this purpose, you will have to ensure that your node js application is integrated with Azure SQL by delegating the application created in Azure AD, the required permissions for that concerned SQL database by allowing access to it** and retrieve the details from it accordingly.

Thus, you can also **configure the token details to be exported from the directory in MySQL DB by configuring the same in your nodejs app** as described in detail in the below link. An excerpt sample from the link is given below for reference: -

In models folder, create User and Role data model as following code:

```
 models/user.model.js

 module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const User = sequelize.define("users", {
   username: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING
   },
   email: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING
   },
   password: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
 });
  return User;
 };
```

***https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-jwt-authentication-mysql/***

Would also suggest you to please refer the below SO community thread for further reference: -

***[MSAL Integration in React + .Net App For all Microsoft Users (Without registering or Inviting the User)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72976568/msal-integration-in-react-net-app-for-all-microsoft-users-without-registerin)***